# How to check the reflected value in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

```
import requests 

arge ="http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=%s" % ("TEST") 
req = requests.get(arge)

if (str(req.text) == '%s'):
    print "Your input found"

else:
    print "Your input not found"
```

What I want to do is to print `"Your input found"` but I always get `"Your input not found"`.

As I am newbie in python I don't know how to achieve it?

Edit:-

When I user this code:-

```
import requests 

input_variable = "TEST"
arge ="http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=%s" % input_variable

req = requests.get(arge)

if (req.text == input_variable):
    print "Your input found"

else:
    print "Your input not found"
```

My file shows the output is "**Your input not found**"  like in the image

[image]

But I can see the input back in the response:-

[image]

Comment: Just use `if input_variable in req.text:` ?

Comment: Perfect Comment. Thankyou @KeyurPotdar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you are trying to pass a parameter to the url and check if the value returned by it is same as the parameter provided.

> `if (str(req.text) == '%s'):`

In the above statement you are trying to compare the contents of the response with a `%s` string , which is never evaluating to `True`.

<strike>Try the following code</strike>

```
import requests 

input_variable = "TEST"
arge ="http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=%s" % input_variable
req = requests.get(arge)

if (str(req.text) == input_variable):
    print "Your input found"

else:
    print "Your input not found"
```

Since the URL you provided was unreachable from my devices, I didn't know what it would return and assumed it works the way you are expecting it to. I.E it just returns what parameters you provide it, but I was wrong.

**Update**:

The `req.text` contains the complete text response that is served by the URL. You will need to process that output to get the parts which highlight the specific part which may contain the parameter provided.

Using `if input_variable in req.text:` will work as well, but it is better to process the response text using some HTML parser and get to the proper div which will contain the input parameter.

Comment: Yes you get it correctly but still I got "you input not found"

Comment: That means that whatever is the response from the URL hit does not match with the `"TEST"`. Try to print `req.text` before the if statement so you can check what is the output you get from the url.
Also Try checking the `req.status_code` returns `200` integer, meaning that the http request succeeds

Comment: Yes, I have done it already, and the result, I can successfully see my input back in the response.

Comment: I dont think that should be the case, can you update question with the output of print statement

Comment: Okay wait, I am now printing the full results,

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Anuj But I got my solution. Recommended to see the comment in above.

Comment: That according to me looks like a hacky way, reason being that the input variables can be inside the url response.

Comment: Then do you have anyother way?

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer to process the response text using some HTML parser

Comment: You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I have read this document. It says we can pull out the data through tag also, But Here I only want my input. I don't care which is in the tag or not. So is the way correct you mention above. And what say anuj?

Comment: As Anuj said, for few cases, the input variable may already be present in the source code. So, it'll return `found` even though it isn't.

Comment: Hey Anuj, I have a new question and I need a little help on that. Here is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642992/how-to-run-a-function-so-it-works-also-when-other-functions-work. Thanks