# How to Capture live request through localhost/XAMPP server?

Tags: xampp

I have a website on which i tried to exploit the XXE vulnerability but contents are not shown on to the website (some filters), so now I am trying **OOB xxe attack**. But for that I need a web server on which I can bring up the request with the file contents.

```
http://localhost/%myentity
```

through that payload in the DOCTYPE I can request the xmlparser to make a request to my localhost server with the file contents. So I can successfully exploit the OOB XXE attack.

It possible for me to capture live request on the XAMPP/localhost server. So that I can bring up the file contents? Hope you know what I mean?