# How to write for loop content in html code python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Below is the code

```
urls.append('http://google.com')
urls.append('http://stacoverflow.com')
 whole = """<html>
<head>
<title>output -</title>
</head>
<body>Below are the list of URLS
%s    // here I want to write both urls.
</body>
</html>"""
for x in urls:
    print x
f = open('myfile.html', 'w')
f.write(whole)
f.close()
```

So this is the code for saving the file in HTML format. But I can't find the way to get the contents of for loop into HTML file. In other words, **I want to write a list of indexes elements i.e. `http://google.com, http://stackoverflow.com` into my HTML file. As you can see that I have created myfile.html as HTML file, So I want to write both URLs which are in the list of indexes into my HTML file**

Hope this time I better explain?
How can I? Would anyone like to suggest me something? It would be a really big help.

Comment: Do you want to create separate HTML files and add sitenames as a `title`?

Comment: Very appreciated that you replied. Thanks for it. I have actually edited my question please see, if you still have any confusion, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
urls.append('http://google.com')
urls.append('http://stacoverflow.com')
whole = """<html>
<head>
<title>output -</title>
</head>
<body>Below are the list of URLS
%s
</body>
</html>"""
f = open('myfile.html', 'w')
f.write(whole % ", ".join(urls))
f.close()
```

Comment: Work like a charm, I don't know how? Really. Any resource to learn?

Comment: Hmm... Actually, it's quite simple: you leave a string placeholder `%s` inside `whole` and `whole % ", ".join(urls)` means *join strings from list `urls` with `", "` separator into single string and substitute `%s` placeholder with resulting string*. I don't know what exactly you might need to learn additionally

Comment: Thanks for it. @Andersson

Comment: Hi, @Andersson This is my new question on selenium based and you will get complete info about it. Please look for at least once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082123/this-code-of-python-is-working-very-slow?noredirect=1#comment91120947_52082123 Thanks:)

Comment: Hi Andersson, I have a new edited question I want to know is my code will work efficiently or not. So I need you help on that. Here is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642992/how-to-run-a-function-so-it-works-also-when-other-functions-work