# How to take multiple screenshots through Selenium in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

```
GECKODRIVER_PATH = 'F:/geckodriver.exe' 

firefox_options = Options()  
firefox_options .add_argument("-headless")  
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, firefox_options = firefox_options )  

test = []
test.append('http://google.com')
test.append('http://stackoverflow.com')

for x in test:
    print x
    driver.get(x)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    filename = str(x)+'.png'
    driver.save_screenshot( filename )
    driver.close()
```

Now, how can I take multiple screenshots and save them in the different filename? As you can see I am trying to save the filename according to domain URL but failed.

See the error below:

```
http://google.com
http://card.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\AutoRecon-master\test.py", line 125, in <module>
    driver.get(x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 326, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the exact problem is? Will be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move `driver.close()` out of loop:

```
for x in test:
    print x
    driver.get(x)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    filename = str(x)+'.png'
    driver.save_screenshot( filename )
driver.close()
```

Also note that `x` is already a string, so there is no need in `str(x)`

P.S. I'm not sure that `http://stackoverflow.com.png` filename is acceptable, you might need to use:

```
filename = x.split('//')[-1] + '.png'
```

Comment: WOW, WOW, and just WOW. Now I can get both png files. Fantastic Job.

Comment: But some questions I have, What is the usage of [-1] in the filename? And will ask you second after this. :)

Comment: `x.split('//')[-1]` means split site-name, e.g. `'http://google.com'` by double slash (the result is list `['http:', 'google.com']`) and select element with index `[-1]` (the last element - `'google.com'`)

Comment: Okay Cool. Thanks for it, Andersson. You just remove a ton of tension.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253530/save-url-as-a-file-name-in-python) for other ways to convert a URL to a valid filename.

Comment: Andersson, I know that this question should now be closed but can you please tell me that I want to make a link in the terminal so that I can see the image by just click on that link. So Is there any-way?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your script to print into terminal output results as clickable links or something like that?

Comment: Yeah! Something like that. :)

Comment: So for now your output is something like `stackoverflow.com.png`, but you want to see some clickable strings that can open the image file from your local folder? I'm not sure that this is kinda simple task actually :) It depends on OS, how exactly you want those "links" to looks like, third-party libs...

Comment: You can run local server from the folder where images will be downloaded with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` and then you can access them via browser by openeing `localhost:8080` - all files should be available as links

Comment: Hi @Andersson, I have posted another question. Would you like to give a try to see it? Here is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970906/how-to-write-for-loop-content-in-html-code-python

Comment: Hi, Andersson, I have posted another new question please see the below question.

Comment: Here is the full url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484845/adding-new-keys-and-value-to-the-older-dictionary-without-changing-the-keys-of-o Looking for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Tried to run command without establishing a connection

you are closing the browser within your for loop... so the 2nd time through the loop it fails with the error above (since the browser is closed, the connection to geckodriver has already been terminated).

other issues:

- you are setting the page_load_timeout after you have already fetched the page, so it is not doing anything useful.
- using CHROMEDRIVER_PATH as the name for Geckodriver is just confusing.  Chromedriver is not used at all here.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry about it. I did use a chrome driver but I forgot to change the name of the variable.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a new question. why not give it a try to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082123/this-code-of-python-is-working-very-slow